# Hibernate Inheritance Mapping with SpringBoot - cast class Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSONNE")
@NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@ClassExtractor(PersonneClassExtractor.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@ToString(of = { "personneId", "perId" })
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "personneId", "perId" })
public class Personne  implements  Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ReturnInsert    
    @Column(name = "PERSONNE_ID")
    protected Long personneId;

..
}
```

and this one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENFANT")
@NamedQuery(name = "Enfant.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Enfant e")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "PERSONNE_ID")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Audit
public class Enfant extends Personne {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
..
}
```

and this:

```
@Repository
public interface EnfantRepository extends PersonneBaseRepository<Enfant>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<Enfant> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM Enfant e WHERE e.personneId = ?1")
    Enfant findOne(Long enfantId);
..
}
```

and

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface PersonneBaseRepository<T extends Personne> 
        extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {

}
```

but when I do

```
Enfant enfant = enfantRepo.findOne(7L);
```

I have this error:

```
 class com.mundos.model.persons.Personne cannot be cast to class com.mundos.model.persons.Enfant (com.mundos.model.persons.Personne and com.mundos.model.persons.Enfant are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @67cae0fe)
```

I also tried `enfantRepo.findById` with the same result

Comment: How did you persist your instance in the database? The error is indicating the row in the database is for a Personne instance, not an Enfant subclass instance, so you likely made a mistake in how you setup the data, not in how you are reading it - though you might want to check the PersonneClassExtractor class that it knows about subclasses and is interpreting the row correctly as a Enfant.

Comment: Do you have spring-boot-devtools in your classpath?

Comment: your entities are in src or in dependency jar?(Which I faced). 
See Holger comment - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536895/cannot-be-cast-to-class-because-they-are-in-unnamed-module-of-loader-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `findOne` method provided by `JpaSpecificationExecutor` contract and the implementation underneath (`SimpleJpaRepository) has seen some changes in different *spring-data-jpa* project versions.

While this is not clear given the reported error, but the runtime may be generating a new query on-fly that does not match your polymorphic structure (you can activate *hibernate* SQL logging to inspect these).

That being said, you are better off using the `findById` and `getById` ready alternatives instead of creating your own query-based method. You should remove your custom `findOne` method out of your `JpaRepository` declaration:

```
@Repository
public interface EnfantRepository extends PersonneBaseRepository<Enfant>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Enfant> {

    // ...
}
```

You are then able to query the `Enfant` entity based on its identifier:

```
Enfant enfant = enfantRepo.findById(7L).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(id));
```

Or simply bypassing the `Optional` return value using the `getById` alternative:

```
Enfant enfant = enfantRepo.getById(7L);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error might be misleading, according to [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536895/cannot-be-cast-to-class-because-they-are-in-unnamed-module-of-loader-app) unless you are explicitly casting in your code.

And not sure both are in same jar|library in your code (depends on your structure)!!  `ERROR: in unnamed module of loader`

Try, This may help if devtools is in your classpath.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

OR

Exclude | Remove

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I faced same issue but it was from different dependency `the unnamed module of loader 'app'``  AND 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615491/tomcat-classcastexception-due-to-classloaders